# Select group of words

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to capture all the words which are bold including the colon.

I am using the following code which is not working.

(1)**This is heading:** This is description of heading; **This is another:** This is another heading description.

(2) **Yet another heading:** This is a description of Yet another heading.

(3) **These are headings:** This is a description of headings; **Another:** This is another heading description.

(4) **This is again a long heading:** Description for this heading.

I have tried following grep which is not working.

`(\w+\s)+:`

Comment: Just know that there is no regex for bold. You should define another criteria instead of the bold-ness.

Comment: I don't have 10 points so I can't post an answer. Bolding appears to be a internal command sent to the text renderers like Rich Text. So in that RTF file anything surrounded with `\b` will be rendered in bold within RTF editors. Good luck. In regex terms that would be `\\b.*?\\b`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using two regex expressions for the two cases:

- `^(.+?):`
- `; (.+?):`

Note that using the `?` operator for lazy or non-greedy match
requires `grep -P` for Perl regex.

The text that is found will include the separators that need to be
removed, but grep isn't the right tool for that.

Comment: None of the code is working. 
It gives "No Matches found"